# Iterm window closes upon start after having ran brew update && brew upgrade (using zsh on Mac)

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh, iterm2

I have updated brew and now iTerm2 window closes immediately. Does anyone know how to fix this?
The commands I ran were `brew update` and `brew upgrade`
I also use ZSH as my default shell. I have read now that upgrading brew and not updating zsh
can cause problems but I don't know how to get back now.

I reposted this question on AskDifferent since this is not the correct place for this.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392686/macos-brew-upgrade-causes-server-version-to-old-for-client-broken-pipe-zsh

Comment: What “closes immediately” mean? Does it mean crash? If so, provide the crash log.

Comment: I mean that the terminal window closes. Iterm is still accessible in the top menu. But the terminal window closes when I run cmd-n for creating a new terminal window. Do you understand what I mean? So I don't think it crashes. Could you please tell me how i find crash logs for iterm?

Comment: I also changed the heading so that the question becomes more clear. Thanks for pointing out wether it crashes or just closes.

Comment: So this is not a programming question. Please move it to AskDifferent.

Comment: Ok thanks! I am not sure I can move it. I don't have enough reputation si think.

Comment: I posted the question on AskDifferent!